# The default 'List' is not available when null safety is enabled

Tags: flutter, dart

error: The default 'List' is not available when null safety is enabled

how do i create an empty array with fixed length in Dart?

```
main(List<String> args) {
  List<int> lista_int_fissa = new List<int>(3);//
  lista_int_fissa[1] = 200;
  print(lista_int_fissa);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace deprecated List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862780/how-to-replace-deprecated-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/the-default-list-constructor-isnt-available-when-null-safety-is-enabled-try)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since null-safety in 2.12 the List constructors have changed to avoid null values. You could use `List.filled(3, 0)` to create a list of 3 zeroes.

```
List<int> lista_int_fissa = List.filled(3, 0);
```

The [documentation about the List constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/List/List.html) indicates that it's now deprecated and suggests using [List.filled](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) instead. You could also create use a literal to create a list

```
List<int> lista_int_fissa = [0, 0, 0];
```

Comment: How can you deal with an object like this :
`new List<Result>()` ?

Answer (score 2):

With Null safety enabled you have to declare your list the following way:

```
var lista_int_fissa = new List<int?>(3);
```